# How to exclude blackout days from a specific duration between two dates chosen from a two Datepicker?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have two **Datepicker** and my object saves the duration between them with an excluding to the blackout days that exist between the two selected days. (every Datepicker has blackout days)

```
          foreach (Model item in listmodels)
                
                {
                    DateFrom.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange((item.startDate), (item.endDate)));
                }

                start_date = DateFrom.SelectedDate.Value;
                end_date = DateTo.SelectedDate.Value;
                var enddate = end_date.Date;
                var startdate = start_date.Date;
                
                leave_days = Convert.ToInt32(enddate.Subtract(startdate).TotalDays);
```

I suppose that the date range (Timespan duration) will be between `3/3/2021` and `3/27/2021`,

What I get is : **24 days**

The duration between these two dates should be ( expected result ) if I exclude `Sunday` and `Saturday` ( weekend) and the blackout days that are presented as holidays : **17 days**

[image]

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: blackout days... never heard, do you mean holidays... like national hols(public hols) these are different from country to country

Comment: Yes, that what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do your calc with code like this

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2021,3,3);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2021,3,27);

// if you want to include the 27 then add + 1 after TotalDays
var days = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(end - start).TotalDays)
          .Select(x => start.AddDays(x))
          .Where(z => z.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && z.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
          .Count();
```

If you have a custom list of days that you have applied to the control as [BlackoutDates](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcalendar/features/blackoutdates) then you can use that collection to exclude them from the count

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2021,3,3);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2021,3,27);

List<DateTime> blackOut = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2021,3,10),
    new DateTime(2021,3,11)
    
};

var days = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(end - start).TotalDays)
          .Select(x => start.AddDays(x))
          .Where(z => z.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && 
                      z.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
                      !blackOut.Contains(z))
          .Count();
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a date range , not a separated days.

Comment: The BlackoutDates are in a date range? You could build a list with the same technique shown above to build the list of date between start and end

Comment: I do this following a solution in StackOverflow but I got an Exception , could you please modify your solution? An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Core.dll
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake ( the exception )

Comment: Good answer, but what if I would like to count the `duration+1` , I mean `(end_date - start_date) +1` for example : if `2021-03-20 - 2021-03-10` , the duration should be 11 not 10 because I would like to count the days of `start_date` and `end_date`

Comment: Just add  + 1 to TotalDays ie: _Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(end - start).TotalDays + 1)_

Comment: That's what I have just writed now , thanks

Comment: I have another question , what if   `Where(z => z.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&  z.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday` present a list , how can I do in this case ? , I mean the weekend days are presented in a list

Comment: Like the _blakOut_ list? Just remove the comparison agains DayOfWeek and use the list with !Contains